# Statistical testing on non-random sample?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, sampling, references, research-design

I am working with a **non-random sample** in an **observational study** but would like to do statistical testing to show certain trends and processes. **Statistical tests assume random sampling**, which is not met in my experiment so my concern is that my results (or interpretation?) are invalid. What options do I have? E.g. should I just be extra careful with the interpretation? Should I remove all text concerning statistical testing?

And the context:

I am conducting a scientometric/bibliometric analysis in **discipline A**. Discipline A is relatively new, but the consensus is that it evolved into a discipline on its own merit over the last 3 or so decades. I identified a certain number of journals based on other scientometric studies and the larger literature, and consider these journals to make up the bulk of discipline A. This list is arguably not exact science and is subjective. The problem of identifying journals is described and explained and justified in my opinion.

I then take this list of journals and analyze trends, such as publication volume over time, contributing countries, etc. so that I can provide insights into journal characteristics, or into the discipline (i.e. all samples journal combined). Sure, the sample is not random, but it still provides insights into the discipline.

Let's say I want to examine a county's economic activity (measured by GPD per capita) and and I fit a linear regression model, which shows that the relationship is statistically significant. How do I go about this? Do I not include statistical testing at all, or do I just make it explicitly clear that what we are seeing refers to the selected set of journals (i.e. that is the whole population).

My **worry** is that what I am doing **may seem dishonest** based on the **discrepancy between the journals I sampled and the discipline** (which is larger), but I am not sure how to resolve the **conflict of wanting to provide insights backed by statistical testing vs. the flaw in sampling** in the process.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, welcome to CrossValidated. I am missing something: what does the analysis on discipline A gas to do with county's economic activity? Sorry I don't understand that part of your question

Comment: @jmarkov That was just an example. I'm sorry if it was too specific and derailed from my main question. In short, exploring this (and related questions) allows me to see if there are disparities, e.g. less developed nations don't participate in the global discourse  compared to their more developed counterparts. Seeing this over time can reveal if we are getting more inclusing. Again, I just wanted to give an example so the specifics are less relevant to the overall question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of your analysis (regression, or whatever you did) are valid for your sample; the effect sizes are accurate estimates for your sample. But the validity of any generalization relies on your sample being random, or, at least, non-biased. But you can't prove that the sample isn't biased.  So, you can either not generalize at all (no inferential statistics) or you can be explicit about what you are doing.

The latter course is done a lot in many disciplines. It is often impossible or extremely difficult to get a random sample. You can argue that your sample is sort-of random, or close to random. You can look at descriptive statistics about your sample and (if possible) compare them to the larger population of journals.  You can add covariates to your model that you think will control some of the bias.

But you can't be certain.

The real danger, in my experience, is that, no matter how careful you are to give limitations and warnings, the findings may be quoted and the warnings and limitations ignored. Then that citation of your findings gets copied and copied. And, if it's wrong by a lot, that's a problem.

OTOH, lots of good studies that had important and useful results were based on non-random samples.

Sorry that that is not a definitive DO THIS answer.

Comment: "But the validity of any generalization relies on your sample being random, or, at least, non-biased" -- unbiasedness (in a specific sense) may be ok for an estimate of some coefficient, but would not be sufficient for estimates of standard errors (and thereby for the usual forms of inference) to be correct. Statistical inference is based on a probabilistic model (e.g. on the basis of random sampling of a population or randomization to treatment). If the sampling or assignment to treatment is not random, then on what basis does the distribution of test statistics (or pivots in CIs) arise?